# wait for preset time, then trigger a function

Tags: python, function, time, clock

using python i have the user enter a preset time. in hours and minutes. and once it is that time, it triggers a function. so i have a loop where every second it checks and if it isnt that time, it check again in once second. but if it is that time i want it to go to that time.

this is the code:

```
while (hour() != schedhr) and (minute() != schedmin):

    time.sleep(1)

    if (schedhr == hour()) and (schedmin == minute()):

         #do function
```

but what happens is, it will wait till the time and then exit as if the script ended instead of doing the function

Comment: you better use time.time() and sleep(.1), and check „<” lower than, since sleep() is a blocking function. After sleep() finish, it may be before or after the sched time, not equal. the sleep(.1) is for while loop let your processor rest

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you, you might use [`time.sleep(seconds)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep)

```
from time import sleep
while (hour() != schedhr) and (minute() != schedmin):
  time.sleep(1)
doFunc() # <-- the timer has ended.
```